# Scala: Mock companion object & Model vs Service approach

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework, mocking

I have seen multiple questions regarding as how to mock a companion object with frequently mentioned answer being to use scalamock but according to the [doc](http://scalamock.org) for version 3, mocking companion objects is still marked for future.

So what is the way to mock a companion object? If not is there a better way to do things than what I already have to enable testing?

Code using play framework:

**Model**

```
case class Article(id: String, preview: String)

object Article {
   def get(id: String) = {
     ......
   }
}
```

**ArticleResource**

```
class ArticleResource extends Controller {
   def getArticle(id: String) = authenticate {
      ......
      Article.get(id)
      ......
   }
}
```

How do I mock `Article.get(id)`?

Before when I had it working, I had structured the code differently:

**Approach for working tests**

**Model**

```
case class Article(id: String, preview: String)
```

**Service**

```
class ArticleService {
   def get(id: String) = {
     ......
   }
}

object ArticleService {
   def apply = new ArticleService
}
```

**ArticleResource**

```
class ArticleResource(articleService: ArticleService) {
   def getArticle(id: String) = authenticate {
      ......
      articleService.get(id)
      ......
   }
}

object ArticleResource extends controllers.ArticleResource(ArticleService())
```

In the test I injected a `mock[ArticleService]` into the Resource for testing.

I kept hearing the former approach (models) is the "right" approach, I never understood why so I tried it and ran into problems into testing and still I do not understand why it is the better approach. (I am actually feeling more strongly towards the latter approach now considering the difficulties with testing)

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to mock companion object?
2. Is there a "right" approach as how code is structured and if so why?

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't think it's possible, and I don't think it's a good idea. I don't think it's desirable to put behavior-that-you-need-to-mock in companion objects.

2) I also believe that your first approach was better. If you want to keep your current code with minimal changes, how about that:

```
case class Article(id: String, preview: String)

object Article {
   def get(id: String) = {
     ......
   }
}

class ArticleResource(articleFinder: (String) => Article = Article.get) {
   def getArticle(id: String) = authenticate {
      ......
      articleFinder(id)
      ......
   }
}
```

And when testing ArticleResource you can just create a function String => Article of your choice. You don't even need a framework for that :)

Edit: You can even use the companion object's method as default value to make it easier to instantiate in production code.

Comment: I cannot pass in a function to `getArticle` because `ArticleResource` is a `Controller` in play framework.

Comment: You might find some interesting options here for that: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal basically, there is a way to manually instantiate your Controllers, so you can give them what you want in their constructor. Good practice for testing as well :)