# NotAMockException when calling static mock in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, static-methods, powermockito

I am trying to use PowerMockito in Scala to bypass a call to `scala.io.Source.fromURL`, which is a static method in the class Source. I have gotten very close to getting this to work, but I keep getting `NotAMockException`.

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ByteInputStream
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import scala.io.BufferedSource
import scala.io.Source

@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[Source]))
class UtilsTest {
  @Test def someTest() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(classOf[Source])
    val a = "hello"
    Mockito.doReturn(
      new BufferedSource(
        new ByteInputStream(a.getBytes, 6), 6))
      .when(Source).fromURL(anyString)
  }
}
```

I get the following error on the `when` line:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I have the class mocked correctly, no?

[EDIT]

My build.sbt (slimmed down, obviously):

```
import _root_.sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin.autoImport._

name := "yahoo-cml"

organization := "com.yahoo"

version := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

lazy val yahooNexusRepo = "Nexus" at "http://pp-nexus.office.yahoo.com/content/groups/public"
lazy val cpArchiva = "cpArchiva" at "http://cp-archiva.office.yahoo.com"
lazy val yahooRepo = "NexusXP" at
  "http://pp-nexus.office.yahoo.com/content/repositories/yahoo-releases"

fullResolvers ++= Seq(
  yahooNexusRepo,
  cpArchiva,
  yahooRepo
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // scalatest is exlcuded due to conflict with testing libraries.
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0" % "provided"
    exclude("org.scalatest", "scalatest_2.11"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
  // Command line parser
  "com.frugalmechanic" %% "scala-optparse" % "1.1.1",
  //  SBT Junit is supported through junit-interface
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test",
  // scalacheck added explicitely to avoid below error due to higher version of scalacheck.
  // "org.scalacheck" % "scalacheck_2.11" % "1.12.5" % "test",
  //  ScalaTest is test framework for scala
  // "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.1" % "test",
  //  Added as this is optional dependency for generating HTML reports in scalatest.
  "org.pegdown" % "pegdown" % "1.6.0" % "test",
  //  spark test framework.
  "com.holdenkarau" % "spark-testing-base_2.11" % "2.1.0_0.6.0" % "test",
  // mockito
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-api-mockito" % "1.7.4" % Test,
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-core" % "1.7.4" % Test,
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-module-junit4" % "1.7.4" % Test,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test,
  // fastUtil efficient type specific collection library
  "it.unimi.dsi" % "fastutil" % "8.2.1"
)

// Create a default Scala style task to run with compile
(scalastyleConfig in Compile) := baseDirectory.value / "scalastyle-config.xml"
lazy val compileScalastyle = taskKey[Unit]("compileScalastyle")
compileScalastyle := org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.scalastyle.in(Compile).toTask("").value
(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn compileScalastyle

// Create a default Scala style task to run with tests
lazy val testScalastyle = taskKey[Unit]("testScalastyle")
testScalastyle := org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.scalastyle.in(Test).toTask("").value
(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn testScalastyle


// Configure Java source code style checking plugin.
checkstyleConfigLocation := CheckstyleConfigLocation.File("checkstyle-config.xml")
checkstyleSeverityLevel := Some(CheckstyleSeverityLevel.Error)
(checkstyle in Compile) <<= (checkstyle in Compile) triggeredBy (compile in Compile)
(checkstyle in Test) <<= (checkstyle in Test) triggeredBy (compile in Test)

// Specifying scalatest style traits for uniformity.
// All scala test classes should extend this style ONLY.
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-y", "org.scalatest.PropSpec")
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
testOptions in Test ++= Seq(Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-o"),
  Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/scala-2.11/scalatest-reports"))
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-oD") // test execution time recording.
parallelExecution in Test := false
fork in Test := true

javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M",
  "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")

// Coverage settings
// Coverage is disabled by default to avoid Scoverage's runtime dependency in application jar.
// Enable coverage explicitly when needed. like,
//   sbt coverage clean test coverageReport
// Do not use coverage when publishing jar
// coverageEnabled := true
coverageMinimum := 70
coverageFailOnMinimum := false
coverageHighlighting := true

// Do not include scala librabries in assembly jar.
assemblyOption in assembly :=
  (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)

// assembly name here should match to same generated by publishLocal.
assemblyJarName := "cml_" + scalaBinaryVersion.value + "-assembly.jar"

// addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly)


// https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/sbt.html
// SBT publish settings.
credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager",
  "pp-nexus.office.yahoo.com",
  "yahooUser", "password")
publishTo <<= version { v: String =>
  val nexus = "http://pp-nexus.office.yahoo.com/"
  if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) {
    Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/yahoo-snapshots/")
  } else {
    Some("releases" at nexus + "content/repositories/yahoo-releases/")
  }
}
```

Comment: If I would be you I would start looking for a solution that doesn't involve mocking a companion object, as it seems to be unsupported. I did a quick search for you, I can't find a hard proof, but look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678415/powermock-not-able-to-mock-static-methods-when-using-scala-junit + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364454/scala-mock-companion-object-model-vs-service-approach Additionally it's often listed as limitation in other scala dedicated mocking libs, and there must be a reason for that.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem but I'm having difficulties, Could you share your dependencies? build.sbt or pom.xml ...

Comment: @fonkap Sure, I'll update the question with the sbt config. Thank you so much for looking into this! I'm completely stumped :/

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note here.

- As a general rule, `object`s hamper your abiliy to test, so, if they extend a trait you should couple to that and then inject the `object` as the default implementation or you just wrap them in your own trait and couple to that.
- Mocks are mainly intended to be used to replace your own classes/traits, not 3rd party ones, so again, the best thing to do here is to wrap that call into your own component (and do an integration test for it) and then couple to that, which will allow you to easily mock it.